# Can I generate patch off private commit and send it to maintainer?

Tags: git

In [Progit](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Maintaining-a-Project#Applying-Patches-from-E-mail) it says:

> If you want Git to try a bit more intelligently to resolve the
>   conflict, you can pass a -3 option to it, which makes Git attempt a
>   three-way merge. This option isn’t on by default because it doesn’t
>   work if the commit the patch says it was based on isn’t in your
>   repository. If you do have that commit — if the patch was based on a
>   public commit — then the -3 option is generally much smarter about
>   applying a conflicting patch:

and

> The other advantage of this approach is that you get the history of
>   the commits as well. Although you may have legitimate merge issues,
>   you know where in your history their work is based; a proper three-way
>   merge is the default rather than having to supply a -3 and hope the
>   patch was generated off a public commit to which you have access.

So does it mean I can base my patch on my *private* commit? I wonder what sense would it make as it would lead to obvious conflicts while merging because the files in commit the patch was based on on contributor's side differ from how my files look now, so how can I incorporate them? These things are described in Progit from the project maintainer's point of view so it's not the case that a contributor would base his patch on some development secret branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A change can easily be based off a private commit, and it will apply as long as the changes are nonconflicting.

Consider:

```
A                   master
\--------B-----C    HEAD
```

A is the upstream (public) master; B and C are commits to a private branch.  You can generate a patch from B to C and if `A..B` and `B..C` are nonconflicting it will apply to the upstream public commit A.

The more polite thing to do is to reorder your commits:

```
A                   master
\--------C-----B    HEAD
```

and submit the patch `A..C`.  If this isn't possible (say, because the intermediate stage commits have been published locally) you should be able to cherry-pick the commits into a branch dedicated to preparing patches for upstream submission:

```
A                   master
\--------B-----C    HEAD
\--------C'         upstream-request
```

Comment: Are there any specific circumstances when it's better to base the patch on the private commit than on the public commit or should it be avoided?

Comment: @user1042840 I can't think of any; if upstream can apply your patch then you can always rewrite it to be based off a public commit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'private commit'; a commit in your local repository?  That is pretty much always what you will submit a patch from.

You want to create a branch in your repository based on the public branch that includes only the commits you want to submit upstream.  Create a patch with `format-patch` from that branch.  Then upstream can apply the patch most easily.

Comment: Yes, I mean a commit in my local repository. My problem is that I don't know what sense does it make to base the patch on my local commit instead of a public one.

Comment: It's generally best to re-order commits (as described in ecatmur's answer) or to use cherry-pick into a dedicated branch for the patch so you can send a patch based only on changes you want to send upstream.  That makes it easier to apply the patch upstream and makes sure you build/test a version corresponding to the patch you are sending.